# Centralized development

Tags: windows, proxy, development-environment, gateway

We are developing ASP.net applications in several windows XP (hyper-v on win 2008 R2) virtual machines, which all connect to internet directly.

We would like to make centralized access point to internet for all virtual machines.

- Developers use Browser (Firefox/IE - HTTP, HTTPS), Outlook (SMTP, POP, IMAP), FTP/SFTP
- Logs to see where do users go on internet
- Restrictions on certain websites (Facebook, MySpace, etc.)

We could setup one xp/vista machine which would be used as some sort of a gateway/proxy.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only possible solution is to use WinGate or Squid proxy. We took Squid.